# Actionscript 3 cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm still really new about classes and stuffs. So, I tried making this and I got an error: Access of undefined property. 
Why speedX and speedY var still error although I've defined it in public var in the main class?

Thanks!

EDITED: I've tried calling the variables from other class with main.speedX and main.speedY
But it got error : Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Ball/moveBall()

This is the Main code:

```
   package
   {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    public var speedX:Number = 5;
    public var speedY:Number = 5;
    public var speedMax:Number = 10;
    private var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
    private var paddle:MovieClip = new Paddle();

    public function Main()
    {
        paddle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePaddle);

        addChild(ball);
        addChild(paddle);
            }

}
```

}

This is the Ball Movie Clip Code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Ball extends MovieClip
{   public var main:Main;

    public function Ball()
    {addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
        main= new Main();
    }
    public function moveBall(e:Event):void
    {
        x += main.speedX;
        y += main.speedY;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Passing the values doesn't work because you are not storing the values in ball. aduch answer works because it passes the values and then stores them in Ball. To clarify, public vars are not globals. They allow you to access the values of a class from outside the class but you still have to reference the class. So if you passed a reference of main to ball you could do something like "_main.speedX" in ball, but "speedX" alone in ball will do nothing.

Comment: I've edited the code. using var from other classes by referencing to Main class with main.speedX. but then i got an error. I think I've been missing something. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? A good reference for Actionscript is Essential Actionscript 3.0 by Colin Moock.

Comment: this error: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at Ball/moveBall(). is that a book ?

Comment: Yes. EA 3.0 is a seminal book on AS and even though older AS3 is still AS3. It might be missing details on the addition of some newer AS3 additions, but those have more to do with specific implementations such as AIR

Comment: oh alright I'll try to search for that book later. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know offhand of any true beginner books that include more complex object oriented programming. However, if you want to start simple, "Flash Game Development by Example" by Emanuele Feronato is really good or his web site at http://www.emanueleferonato.com

Comment: i've read a few things there a while ago. Going to learn more in the weekend. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another possible solution where you would be passing main to ball to use the values of speed stored in Main.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var speedX:Number = 5;
    private var ball:MovieClip;
    public function Main()
    {
        ball=new Ball(this);
        addChild(ball);
     }

}
```

and

```
public class Ball extends MovieClip
{   
      private var _main:Main;
      public function Ball(main:Main)
      {
          _main=main;
          addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
      }

      public function moveBall(e:Event):void
      {
          x += _main.speedX;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: it works really well! Thanks a lot. But I'm still confused about a few things. first of all what's the difference between defining "ball= new Ball;" in var and in main function? Second, what does "(this)" in "ball=newBall(this)" do? I often found it on tutorials but I never understand what is it for and what it does. Can you please explain? Thanks a lot once again

Comment: Its usually best to define only simple values in the variable definition like you do with speed. More complicated definitions should be done in class functions. In this case, "this" which is Main, doesn't exists yet in the variable definition so it couldn't be assigned anyways. Also, defining variables in their definition can slow down your code. "this" refers to the enclosing thing. So in this case, this is a reference to the object created by the class of Main i.e. its a reference to itself.

Comment: alright I understand the first one. but about the "(this)", what I can conclude is: "(this)" is used for saying that ball is from main class; in order to give the access for the variables (speedX) in ball class to the defined variables in class which the ball referred to. Is it that right? Thanks! I get many things from what you've taught.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your class Ball cannot access speedX and speedY inside the event callback. Why not add `speedX` and `speedY` to your `Ball` class directly instead ?

```
public class Ball extends MovieClip
{   
    public var speedX:Number;
    public var speedY:Number;

    public function Ball(sX:Number = 0, sY:Number = 0)
    {
        this.speedX = sX;
        this.speedY = sY;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
    }

    public function moveBall(e:Event):void
    {
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I understand a bit more now. But, does the var needed to be defined in each class? Can we just defined it in main class for the rest of the other classes? (like i did previously). Thanks

Comment: Well it depends pretty much on what you're trying to achieve, if you need it for other classes you may think of another way to tackle the problem..

Comment: So I can't just write public var in the main class to be used for another classes? I guess I need to try a lot of things. Thanks

Comment: No indeed you can't... speed is intrinsic to your object anyways. But you could still wrap it inside a class like MovablesManager and this class has properties speedX and speedY, and calls a method move on a collection of objects (like balls) with its property speedX and speedY as parameters of this method move.

Comment: well guess it's still better for me to define it in the class which need it. I haven't really understood all the things though. Thanks. Anyway, do you know any good tutorial sites for classes that I can learn?

Comment: This may interest you http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introducing-design-patterns--active-8278